# How to resolve HttpServletRequest can not be cast to custom HttpServletRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, servlet-3.0

controller code is

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc/test.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getData(@RequestParam(value="qName", required=true) String qName,                                           
                                           HttpServletRequest request,
                                           Model model) {        

        OverridableHttpRequest myRequest = (OverridableHttpRequest) request;
```

--
OverridableHttpRequest is as below

```
public class OverridableHttpRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper implements
        HttpServletRequest {
    private Map<String, String> newParams;
    private Set<String> removedParams;
    public OverridableHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest requestToWrap) {
        super(requestToWrap);
        this.newParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.removedParams = new HashSet<String>();
    }
}
```

I am upgrading to spring boot 2.4.2

Comment: You really shouldn't cast (generally speaking) it could even be that there are more filters that wrap the request (which is what properly happens).

Comment: I was trying to create object this way.  OverridableHttpRequest myRequest = new OverridableHttpRequest(request); I was getting the following exception. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean specified
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[commons-lang-2.6.jar!/:2.6]

Comment: You need a filter that wraps the request and still that is not a guarantee that the request you receive is an instance of that wrapped request. There can be more filters in the chain wrapping it with a different request wrapper. But generally speaking if your downstream code requires this you are probably doing it wrong. What is it you are trying to solve?

Comment: session.getAttribute("sortColumnOrder"); gives null. because of httpSession. at front end we are using display table. Could you please help to resolve?

Comment: I modified the code to OverridableHttpRequest myRequest =  new OverridableHttpRequest(request)

Comment: UNless you are doing that in a filter, that code is wrong.